# Razor component rendering order

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

Good morning,
As part of my work, we use Blazor, including Razor components to implement openid connect.

I need to fetch the authorization code from querystring, then use it to make a post request to an API fetching some text and displaying it in the component, the code is working but rendering is still empty.
So I did a Console.WriteLine to see and realized that the result is indeed obtained, except that the update component itself as soon as the information changes which again triggers a second request whose code n is no longer valid.

I'm familiar with reactjs hooks, wondering if I put this statement in the wrong event (**protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync**) or is there the equivalent of the hooks that I don't know about?

thank you so much

Comment: Have a read through https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/